# Change visibility of all simple products

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I'm trying to change visibility of all SIMPLE-only products via SQL.

Here is how I select all values of visibility attribute:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` WHERE attribute_id = 102
```

`catalog_product_entity_int` table has `entity_id` column which is product entity ID, and `value` that should be changed to `1` for all simple products.

Here is how I select all simple products:

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `type_id`= 'simple'
```

What I can't do, is write query that would update `value` column of `catalog_product_entity_int` for all simple products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i got ur question, this simple code will be work for u.

i assume that relationship between these two tables are -entity_id

```
update catalog_product_entity_int set value =1 
where attribute_id = 102 and  entity_id=
(select entity_id from `catalog_product_entity` where `type_id`= 'simple')
```

Comment: The problem is that type_id is in different table. :(

Comment: is there any sort of connection between these two tables?

Comment: there must be some sort of connection beteween these two tables .. otherwise we can't do it.. ( i mean any relationships?)

Comment: Thank you very much much, this works as it should. Except I added ANY (... entity_id= ANY (select entity_id from `catalog_produ ... ), because there are multiple entity_id's.

Comment: the select will return multiple entity_ids this should be corrected

Answer (score 4):

Do you have any reason to edit EAV attribute with direct sql query?

You could do the same using collections or even at admin backend: catalog - manage products - type "Simple product" - Select all - Actions - Update Attributes - Visibility

Comment: This was a perfect solution for me, thank you for such simplicity

Answer (score 3):

Exactly working query

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int CPI INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity CP ON CPI.entity_id = CP.entity_id
SET value = 1 
WHERE CPI.attribute_id = 102 AND CP.type_id = 'simple';
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use one of Magento's mass actions.  This way the proper events are still dispatched.

```
<?php

// Get all simple product ids
$ids = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_SIMPLE))
    ->getAllIds();

// Update their visibility
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
    $ids,
    array("visibility" => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE),
    Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the steps.

Step1: Before make the any changes through query you need to take the backup of effected table or database. In this case take backup (catalog_product_entity_int) table.

Step2: Search for the exact visibility attribute id in the eav_attribute table.

(`SELECT *  FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code LIKE 'visibility'`). Then keep that value in following query...

Step3: Run this query

`UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET VALUE =2 WHERE attribute_id = 102 AND entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity WHERE type_id= 'simple')`

Good luck...

Comment: Kudos for (seemingly, I am no SQL expert) correct answer to a question asked 3 years ago!

Answer (score -1):

I think This sql command which exactly:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET VALUE =2  
WHERE attribute_id = 93 AND  
      entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM catalog_product_entity 
                    WHERE type_id= 'simple')
```

Note: Check your attribute_id witch mapped number